# Find the number of occurences of certain string sequences

Tags: linux, string, grep, debian, cat

I want to count the number of occurences of the IP address `192.168.1.10` in a text file using `grep | wc`.

The command I use is:

```
cat ./capture.txt|grep "192.168.1.10"|wc -w
```

which returns 0, and I don't know why.

Here is the content of my .txt file:

[image]

Comment: Its not useful to link to a picture of text.  Cut and paste the relevant text into your question.  That makes it self contained, and readable

Comment: sorry, for the misspell - cat ./capture.txt|grep "192.168.1.10", but still i don't get the desired effect

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
grep -Fwo '192.168.1.10' file|wc -l
```

- `-F` makes the grep take your pattern as literal string instead of regex
- `-w` excludes `192.168.1.101` or `192.168.1.100`
- `-o` lists each match in a line. grep does line based match, if your pattern matched twice in a line, the result of occurrence count may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat ./capture.txt | grep "\b192\.168\.1\.10\b" -c
```

- `\.` search for dot, not any character
- `\b` match at the beginning or end of a word
- `-c` return the number of occurrences